# WSO2 APIM context and version on url path

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm working with WSO2 APIM 4.2 and the URL gateaway path looked like this.

```
Https://ourdomain.com:8243/context/version/resource
```

Can I position the url to /version/context/resource or eliminate the version and context completely?

So the URL only contains `https://ourdomain.com:8243/resource`

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the order of `context` and the `version`. Having said that, context is the unique identifier of each API. So you need to have a context for every API. What you can do is create an API per resource in that case. You can get rid of the version by making the API have a [default](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-versioning/backward-compatibility/) version. Then the API URL will look like below.

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/something/
```

Comment: The docs shows we can make one version as the default with exact same context. How do we have 2 apis with same context?

Comment: I really don't understand your use case here. Why do you want to create multiple APIs with the same context?

Comment: Sorry it's a misunderstanding from my side. Thank you for answering! 